# colortbl & dcolumn: Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\tabpre): `c' used

Tags: arrays, colortbl, dcolumn

While using the packages `colortbl`, `dcolumn` for the scenario described in MWE, I am getting the below error message:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{color}

\def\tabpre{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|p{5pc}|c|D{.}{.}{2,2}|c|}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{\tabpre}\hline
1aa&bb&cc&cc\\\hline
2aa&bb&cc&cc\\\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

...some text...

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{\tabpre}\hline
1aa&bb&4.00&cc\\\hline
2aa&bb&10.01&cc\\\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: `d{2,2}` doesn't exist. Check the documentation of dcolumn about the right syntax.

Comment: `array` package tabular do not expand macros in the tabular preamble so you can not use \def\tabpre`

Comment: Using `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` makes sense only when using a `tabular*` environment. It's of no relevance when using a `tabular` environment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer modified MWE based on your comments.

Comment: @David Carlisle - Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: @Mico - Modified MWE based on your comments.

Comment: use `\newcolumntype\tabpre`.

Comment: as Ulrike says.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - it works. Please mention this as solution, so that, I can close this request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use \newcolumntype to store a tabular preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{color}

\newcolumntype\tabpre{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|p{5pc}|c|D{.}{.}{2,2}|c|}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{\tabpre}\hline
1aa&bb&cc&cc\\\hline
2aa&bb&cc&cc\\\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

...some text...

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{\tabpre}\hline
1aa&bb&4.00&cc\\\hline
2aa&bb&10.01&cc\\\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```